# Copy activity met storage operation failure at 'Source' side. Error message from storage execution

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am getting error when I query data from PerformanceCountersTable using Timestamp column like this,
Copy activity met storage operation failure at 'Source' side. Error message from storage execution : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. One of the request inputs is not valid

Here is my Pipeline activity:

```
        "activities": [
            {
                "type": "Copy",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureTableSource",
                        "azureTableSourceQuery": "$$Text.Format('(CounterName eq \\'\\Process(WaWorkerHost)\\% Processor Time\\' or CounterName eq \\'\\Memory\\Available MBytes\\') and Timestamp ge datetime \\'{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ}\\' and Timestamp lt datetime \\'{1:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ}\\'', SliceStart, SliceEnd)"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlSink",
                        "writeBatchSize": 0,
                        "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "MetricsDataVMCPUinput"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "MetricsDataVMCPUoutput"
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "00:15:00",
                    "concurrency": 1,
                    "retry": 3
                },
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 15,
                    "style": "EndOfInterval"
                },
                "name": "MetricsDataVMCPUactivity"
            }
```

When I change the Azuretablesourcequery like this,without Timestamp:
`CounterName eq \\'\\Process(WaWorkerHost)\\% Processor Time\\' or CounterName eq \\'\\Memory\\Available MBytes\\'`

I am getting data properly. I don't know whats the error with this query !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`400` error means some incorrect data is supplied to Table Service. On inspecting your query

```
"azureTableSourceQuery": "$$Text.Format('(CounterName eq \\'\\Process(WaWorkerHost)\\% Processor Time\\' or CounterName eq \\'\\Memory\\Available MBytes\\') and Timestamp ge datetime \\'{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ}\\' and Timestamp lt datetime \\'{1:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ}\\'', SliceStart, SliceEnd)"
```

I noticed that there's a space between `datetime` and the date/time value. This could cause the request to table service to fail with 400 error.

Please try by removing the space. So your query would be:

```
"azureTableSourceQuery": "$$Text.Format('(CounterName eq \\'\\Process(WaWorkerHost)\\% Processor Time\\' or CounterName eq \\'\\Memory\\Available MBytes\\') and Timestamp ge datetime\\'{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ}\\' and Timestamp lt datetime\\'{1:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ}\\'', SliceStart, SliceEnd)"
```

Another thing I noticed is that you're querying on `Timestamp` value. This is bad because it will cause full table scan. Instead use `PartitionKey` in your query. Essentially what you have to do is convert `SliceStart` and `SliceEnd` to ticks and prepend a `0` to that value. I have written a blog post about the same that you may find useful: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/.